# I can not access my old data in Google Analytics after migrating to GA4

Tags: google-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2LLI.jpg)I migrated to GA4 about two months ago and now need website data from September 2022 to September 2023. But I am not able to receive the old data (UA). Is there any way to recover that data?

I added the tracking code (UA) to the head section of my website, created with wordpress. I would like to know is there any way to back to UA and all the old data?

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly why the hype of GA4 migration happened a year before the original UA decommissioning date. To not lose the ability to do the YoY analysis.

Since you've only migrated two months ago, you effectively lost access for the relevant history for YoY.

If you really need it, the feasible solution now is to export all your UA data (that is if you still have access to it) to BQ using ETL tools, then do the same with GA4 data and then do some SQLing to compare two datasets. Just don't expect the data to have the same structure. GA4 inherited the data structure from Firebase. It looks different from UA's data. Comparing them will be tough. The definition of a session changed too, which will make it a lot harder to compare the two datasets. People still do it, but they have to compensate for a lot of new factors.